# Codeigniter "file_exists($filename)"

Tags: file, codeigniter, path

Need help with the codeigniter, I think file_exists is for server path, not for url. but my image folder got same level with application and system folder. find nothing on google, please help

```
$url=base_url();
$filename="$url/upload/$id.jpg";
if (file_exists($filename)){
    echo "<li><img src=\"".$url."upload/$id.jpg\" width=\"40\" height=\"40\" /></li>";
}else{
    echo "<li><img src=\"http://www.mydomain.com/haha/image/noimg.png\" width=\"40\" height=\"40\" /></li>";
}
```

Comment: One thing, file_exists *is* for server paths, not urls.  So you wouldn't use base_url(), you'd use APPPATH

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Codeigniter is always running on `index.php`, so all paths are relative from there. You can use any of the following, assuming `upload/` is at the same level as `index.php`:

- `file_exists("upload/$id.jpg")`
- `file_exists("./upload/$id.jpg")`
- `file_exists(FCPATH."upload/$id.jpg")`

`FCPATH` is a constant that Codeigniter sets which contains the absolute path to your `index.php`.

As a side note, I prefer `is_file()` when checking files, as `file_exists()` returns true on directories. In addition, you might want to see if `getimagesize()` returns `FALSE` to make sure you have an image.

Comment: my data have the image full path..eg..(http://localhost/media/newsdata/20150923/Entertainment/Casspture.PNG) it is worng when i use file_exists($thisfile), it was always return false..please

Comment: Use only the server path: `file_exists('media/newsdata/20150923/Entertainment/Casspture.PNG')`

Comment: what if the user has encrypted the name of file while uploading it then how should we check?  @WesleyMurch

Comment: `@getimagesize()` will return false if there is no file existing and hide a warning message