# CodeIgniter file_exists not working properly

Tags: php, codeigniter

I saw several identical topics such as [Codeigniter "file_exists($filename)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9218492/codeigniter-file-existsfilename), http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/79524/#399857., but did not worked for me.

In my URL(`dashboard/products/`) I call a function from the helper, and the function is the following:

```
if(!function_exists('getImage')){

    function getImage($image){

        $path = base_url() . 'public/images/';

        if(file_exists($path . $image) === FALSE || $image == null){
            return $path . "no_image.png";
        }

        return $path . $image;
    }
}
```

Then in my file `content.php` which is the `view` of `dashboard/products`, I use that function this way:

```
<img src="<?php echo getImage($row->picture); ?>" class="thumbnail-image"/>
```

This always returns `no_image.png` and the problem is caused by `base_url()` in the `file_exists` function (from what I read from other similiar topics).

The solutions told in that topics were the following:

```
1) - file_exists(dir_name(FCPATH)."/gallery/member_picture/member_no_image.gif")
2) - file_exists("./gallery/member_picture/member_no_image.gif")
```

And I've tried all of them and none worked. Just for the case, my current URL is: `http://localhost/myproject/dashboard/products`

**Solution 1)**

```
if(file_exists(dirname(FCPATH) . "/public/images/" . $image) === FALSE || $image == null){
    return $path . "no_image.png";
}
```

Does not work. If I output the values I receive the following:

```
return dirname(FCPATH) . "/public/images/" . $image;
//output to img src:
<img src="C:\xampp\htdocs/public/images/users/1/image_name.jpg" class="thumbnail-image">
```

Also, If I open the `src` link in another tab the URL changes to: `http:// localhost/myproject/dashboard/C:/xampp/htdocs/public/images/users/1/image_name.jpg`

**Solution 2)**

Again, adapting that to my code:

```
return "./public/images/" . $image;
//output to img src:
<img src="./public/images/users/1/image_name.jpg" class="thumbnail-image">
```

Opening the link of `src` in a new tab, the URL changes to:

```
http://localhost/myproject/dashboard/public/images/users/1/image_name.jpg
```

Which is wrong. It should be:

```
http://localhost/myproject/public/images/users/1/image_name.jpg
```

So, that said, how d'hell am I suppose to verify if the image exists or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**.

Since the problem was on `file_exists()` and it seems that the function goes to the root directory, all I had to do was to change a little the algorithm.

```
function getImage($image){

    if(file_exists('public/images/' . $image) == FALSE || $image == null){
        return base_url() . './public/images/no_image.png';
    }

    return base_url() . './public/images/' . $image;
}
```